# How to install open cv 2.4.9 on mac using pip?

Tags: opencv

I was trying to install open cv 2.4.9 binary using pip on mac but I am not being able to do so/

Comment: Follow this link: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Why 2.4.9 but not 2.4.12 or 3.2.0?